# Find dy/dx of this function.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

The function under consideration is:

$$y = \int_{x^2}^{\sin x}\cos(t^2)\mathrm d t$$

Question asks to find the derivative of the following function. I let $u=\sin(x)$ and then $\tfrac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d x}=\cos(x)$. Solved accordingly but only to get the answer as 
$$ \cos(x)\cos(\sin^2(x))-\cos(x)\cos(x^4) $$ 
but the answer is given as:
 $$ \cos(x)\cos(\sin^2(x))-2x\cdot\cos(x^4) $$

May I know where I went wrong? Is my substitution wrong in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

The fundamental theorem of calculus write $$\frac d {dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\,dt=f(b(x)) b'(x)-f(a(x)) a'(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

You have, in fundamental theorem terms, the expression $y=F(\sin x)-F(x^2)$ where $F'(t)=f(t)=\cos(t^2)$. Thus
$$
y'(x)=F'(\sin x)·\cos x-F'(x^2)·2x=f(\sin x)·\cos x-f(x^2)·2x
$$
per the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Let us say that $F $ is a primitive of $cos(t^2) $. Hence the integral of $y $ can be written as

$$y = \int_{x^2}^{sin\ x} cos(t^2) dt = F(sin\ x) - F(x^2) $$

Hence you can derive $y $ by deriving the rightmost expression and by making use of the fact that $F'  = cos(t^2) $.

$$y' = (F(sin\ x))' - (F(x^2))' = (cos\ x)\cdot F'(sin\ x) - 2x F'(x^2) = cos\ x\cdot(cos(sin^2 x)) - 2x(cos\ x^4)$$

Without seeing all your calculations it is hard to tell where you went wrong but it must have been a minor error when differentiating everything. Maybe a chain rule that you got wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, when i to solve this kind of problem i usually do the following.

1) I define a two variable function like:

$$F(u,v) = \int_{v}^{u} \cos(t^2)dt.$$

2) What we want to calculate is $$\frac{dy}{dx}(x)$$ where $y(x) =  F(\sin(x),x^2)$. Then we have:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\{F(\sin(x),x^2)\} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial u}(\sin(x),x^2)\frac{d}{dx}\{\sin(x)\}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial v}(\sin(x),x^2)\frac{d}{dx}\{ x^2\}.$$

Since $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial u} = \cos(u^2),$$
and $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial v} = -\cos(v^2),$$
we obtain
$$\frac{dy}{dx}(x) =  \cos(\sin^2(x))\cos(x)-2x\cos(x^4).$$

Comment: partial derivatives or multi-variable calculus might be outside the scope of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that  \begin{split} \int \limits_{x^{2}}^{\sin{x}} \cos{t^{2}}\,dt &= \int \limits_{x^{2}}^{a} \cos{t^{2}}\,dt + \int \limits_{a}^{\sin{x}} \cos{t^{2}}\,dt \\ &= \underbrace{-\int \limits_{a}^{x^{2}} \cos{t^{2}}\,dt}_{A} + \underbrace{\int \limits_{a}^{\sin{x}} \cos{t^{2}}\,dt}_{B} \end{split}

Then $\frac{d}{dx} \left(  \int \limits_{x^{2}}^{\sin{x}} \cos{t^{2}}\,dt \right ) = \underbrace{-\cos(x^{4})2x}_{\text{chain rule applied to A}} + \underbrace{\cos(\sin^{2}(x))\cos(x)}_{\text{chain rule applied to B}}$.